# Select distinct varchar values from a column in existing table, convert to int and insert into temp table within one step

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to select distinct values from a varchar column of an existing table into a temp table and simultaneously convert those inserted values to int within one statement?

If so what would the statement structure be?

If not what would be an alternative approach?

I've tried the following:

```
Select DISTINCT Convert(int, column_name) Into #temp 
From source_table 
Where column_name IS NOT NULL
```

but Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio warns...

> No column specified for column 1 of '#temp'.

... and I'm not sure how to fix this error.

If possible I would like to refrain from opening a cursor to iterate through the existing table and converting the values iteratively.

Comment: The issue here is that you did not give your converted column a name.  Please see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select DISTINCT cast(column_name as int) as column_name
 Into #temp From source_table Where column_name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much it worked. I will accept after the time restriction to accept an answer expires.

Comment: @GregHess Basically the SELECT INTO #temp is creating a new table and without a name for the column (difference between your attempt and this answer) it doesn't know how to structure/create the table hence the error you received.

Comment: @Matt thanks for the descriptive info man. Yea I just realized as I saw the answer I had a bit of a face palm moment it makes total sense looking back at it now.